# Internet connection problem in ubuntu

Tags: internet

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and sometimes I'm unable to connect to Internet. After adding a DSL connection in my network connection preferences, DSL connection1 isn't visible anymore. When trying to connect using the `pppoeconf` command, the command is completeyed but when checking the connection using `plog` I get:

> Aug 14 21:49:38 vijay pppd[887]: Compression disabled by peer.
>   Aug 14 21:49:38 vijay pppd[887]: Could not determine local IP address
>   Aug 14 21:49:38 vijay pppd[887]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
>   Aug 14 21:49:38 vijay pppd[887]: Sent 118 bytes, received 138 bytes.
>   Aug 14 21:49:38 vijay pppd[887]: Connection terminated

After trying 5 to 6 time able to connect to internet. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing driver ?

```
      sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```